# ¿Cómo hacer que se vayan añadiendo sucesivamente diferentes selecciones de texto en innerHTML con javascript?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

¿Alguien que sepa podría ayudarme?... porque estoy trabado con este problema:

Estoy haciendo un selector de texto desde un textarea y me gustaría que el texto seleccionado aparte no sustituya al que está ya ahí, sino que se añada a continuación, es decir, que cuando se ejecute la función el resultado no sea siempre el último borrando lo anterior.

El código es el siguiente:

```js
function seleccionar(){

        let inicio = areatexto.selectionStart;
        let fin= areatexto.selectionEnd;
        let texto = areatexto.value;
        let sel = texto.substring(inicio, fin);

        if(sel.length > 0){


        areatexto.setRangeText(sel, inicio, fin, 'select');
        
        resultado.innerHTML = sel; 
        
        resultado.appendChild(resultado.innerHTML); //aquí falla

      } 

    }
      
      boton.addEventListener('click', function(){seleccionar()});
```

```html
<textarea id="areatexto" cols="50" rows="8">Esto es un texto de prueba.</textarea>
  <p><button id="boton">Seleccionar</button></p>
  
  <p id="resultado"></p>
```

*NOTA: Por favor, no me lo expliquen en jQuery, sino en javascript puro.

Answer (score 4):

Podrías probar `resultado.innerHTML += sel;` en lugar de `resultado.innerHTML = sel;` Lo de appendChild no lo necesitas al modificar lo anterior.

```js
function seleccionar() {

  let inicio = areatexto.selectionStart;
  let fin= areatexto.selectionEnd;
  let texto = areatexto.value;
  let sel = texto.substring(inicio, fin);

  if(sel.length > 0){


    areatexto.setRangeText(sel, inicio, fin, 'select');

    resultado.innerHTML += sel; 

  //resultado.appendChild(resultado.innerHTML); //aquí falla
  }
} 

boton.addEventListener('click', function(){seleccionar()});
```

```html
<textarea id="areatexto" cols="50" rows="8">Esto es un texto de prueba.</textarea>
  <p><button id="boton">Seleccionar</button></p>
  
  <p id="resultado"></p>
```